# How do I stop URLs that don't exist from resolving to a file?

Tags: php, apache

I don't know if this is an Apache or PHP thing but if you go to either of:

```
mysite.com/about
mysite.com/about/
```

it will show the `mysite.com/about.php` file instead of a 404 error, because the directory does not exist.

I am sure this is some setting, maybe an htaccess thing, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have answered it might be a mod_rewrite rule; there is also a directive called `MultiViews` that is explicitly for enabling the functionality you describe.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews

> The effect of MultiViews is as
>   follows: if the server receives a
>   request for /some/dir/foo, if
>   /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and
>   /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the
>   server reads the directory looking for
>   files named foo.*, and effectively
>   fakes up a type map which names all
>   those files, assigning them the same
>   media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for
>   one of them by name. It then chooses
>   the best match to the client's
>   requirements.

Look for

```
Options MultiViews
```

in your httpd.conf or virtualhost-specific config file.

Comment: Glad to help.  MultiViews is great for some (prevents a lot of playing with .htaccess files and mod_rewrite rules) and the bane of others.

Answer (score 3):

That's not default behavior, for sure, so it's hard to say. If that were happening on the Apache side, look for a sequence of rewrite matching instructions; they'll likely begin with `RewriteCond` and ending with `RewriteRule`.

If you don't see anything like that in your `VirtualHost` config or site `.htaccess`, it's being managed by whatever PHP framework you're using, and you'll need to configure things there instead.

Comment: +1 That is definitely not a default PHP / Apache setup. I'm suspecting a `mod_rewrite` directive or that one module that can suggest alternative file names for incomplete request, I forgot its name...

Answer (score 0):

with this .htaccess you can parse, with $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] in the PHP side, the complete URL and then perform your desired action, this is a general way, you should consider error controlling and 404 redirection:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and int the PHP side, that should be this index.php

```
$URLarray = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```